# Python leading underscore _variables

Tags: python

We know that in a class, functions starting with `__function__` do not get imported while using:

```
from module import *
```

Someone asked what is an `_variable`? I have never used one.
Do they exist?  Is this a concept of variable which cannot be accessed using class object or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a naming convention for private variables. See 9.6, private variables: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Answer (score 7):

A variable name starting with an underscore is a strong hint that this variable should be viewed as private.

Read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables